# Aggregating a list of users IDs who have installed my Facebook app

Tags: javascript, facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps, facebook-canvas

I have an App with close to a million installed users. But as the user base grew, I failed to store the user IDs who installed my app in my database. Now I am alarmed to find that Facebook API offers no direct method to do that. How do I go about finding the users who installed my app now?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I go about finding the users who installed my app now?

By saving their ID next time they actively use your app.

No, there is no other way.

Comment: I am wondering if there's a way to go about iteratively testing all userIDs to see if they have my app installed? Will this be against Facebook Developer ToS?